# Problema al intentar ingresar un dato para un objeto

Tags: java, poo

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Entrada**texto en negrita**
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Objetos
    System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
    String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su edad");
    int edad = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su sexo (H)Hombre (M)Mujer");
    char sexo = entrada.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Ingrese su peso en kg");
    float peso = entrada.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su altura en m");
    float altura = entrada.nextFloat();

    Persona objeto1 = new Persona(nombre, edad, sexo, peso, altura);

    System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
    String nombre2 = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su edad");
    int edad2 = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese su sexo (H)Hombre  (M)Mujer");
    char sexo2 = entrada.next().charAt(0);

    Persona objeto2 = new Persona(nombre2, edad2, sexo2);
```

En el codigo que les muestro, funciona correctamente hasta la primera
instancia "objeto1" cuando pasa a la siguiente linea donde vuelve a
pedir el nombre al usuario para el "objeto2" no lo reconoce y se pasa
defrente a pedir la edad. ¿A que se debe eso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que invocas a los métodos [nextFloat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat--), [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), etc, el búfer del teclado quedará sucio, es decir, con un salto de línea.

Entonces si invocas al método `nextLine` después de un `nextFloat`, la rutina no pausará el programa porque el búfer no está limpio.

**Solución:** Limpia el búfer antes de pedir el nombre de la persona:

```java
System.out.println("Ingrese su altura en m");
float altura = entrada.nextFloat();

Persona objeto1 = new Persona(nombre, edad, sexo, peso, altura);

/* Limpia el búfer */
entrada.nextLine();
System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre");
String nombre2 = entrada.nextLine();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.